# PowerShell - Get Version from .csproj file

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm learning PowerShell. Right now, I'm trying to get the `Version` element value from a .csproj file. The .csproj file's XML looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyLibrary" Version="3.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In an attempt to get the `Version` element value from this XML, I've written the following PowerShell script:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content ./MyApp.csproj)

Write-Host "xml: " $xml

$version = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version

Write-Host "version: $version"
```

When I run this script, I see the following:

```
xml:

version:
```

Notice that neither the project XML, nor the version gets written. At first, I thought I was referencing the .csproj incorrectly. I intentionally removed the "j" at the end and an error was thrown. For that reason, I'm assuming that I'm properly loading the .csproj content. However, I believe I'm not parsing the XML properly in my PowerShell script.

How do I get the `Version` from the .csproj value in the PowerShell script?

Comment: Output from `Write-Host` cannot be redirected.

Comment: I have your code working, try to check permissions on the file.
Just need to fix it like this: Write-Host "xml: $xml"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As noted, `Write-Host` is output-only and cannot be redirected. Other than that, I can't reproduce it. This works for me:

```
$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content .\MyApp.csproj)
$version = [Version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version
```

(The cast to `[Version]` makes it easier to get the individual parts of the version, compare with other versions, etc.)

Comment: Is there a way to print variable values to the console window? I thought that's the purpose of `Write-Host`.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Write-Host` to output values to the console, but just be aware of its limitations.

Comment: This didn't work for me, as the XML version element is an array. What worked was:
$version = [Version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version[0]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the folder containing the .csproj file, then run the following commands

$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content .\DEPLOY.Cachorro.Api.csproj)
$version = [Version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.AssemblyVersion

You also need to make sure if your version is within the AssemblyVersion or Version tag. I´m using AssemblyVersion
[image]

Then you can execute the command to know the value stored in your "version" variable

Write-Host "version: $version"

Take a look:

[image]