# How can I add "pre-release" to a package name and push it to an Azure DevOps feed?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have it set up so that it pushes the package version defined in the `.csproj` file and is triggered based off master.  Is there a way I can basically command the package to have a name such as `pre-release-`(package version defined in `.csproj`) on a commit to a branch that is NOT master?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Added variable definition.

Sure, you can accomplish this by changing the Version pipeline variable within your pipeline depending on which branch is being built.

In your case, you'll want to add a Version variable within your Stage/Pipeline variables:

```
variables:
  - name: Version
    value: ""
```

Then, add this task before you attempt to pack & push your artifacts:

```
- script: |
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]pre-release-$(Version)'
    echo "Setting Version to pre-release-$(Version)"
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
```

Once the variable is set to your prerelease name, you'll want to pass in the version to your NuGet push, like this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Run NuGet Pack"
  inputs:
    command: "pack"
    packagesToPack: "yourproject.csproj"
    versioningScheme: "off"
    buildProperties: Version=$(Version)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked. It doesn't realize what `$(Version)` is. The log: `Setting Version to pre-release-
/home/vsts/work/_temp/ab79fe90-2191-49c8-983f-162e4c392dce.sh: line 2: Version: command not found
`

Comment: My apologies, I didn't make it clear that "Version" was a custom variable in this instance. You'll need to add it as a variable within your Stage or Pipeline variables. I've updated my post to include that step as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. I need the Version to be set to what's in my .csproj file. If I'm understanding this correctly, this will just set the value to be `pre-release-` since Version equals nothing.

Comment: Hi @TheVanillaThrilla, We could read the .csproj file and match the field version, then set the the value to the variable Version.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT is correct, the example above assumes you'd be setting the "Version" pipeline variable to what's within your project file.

Comment: Thank you.  How would I go about reading the `.csproj` file? As of right now, I'm not reading it for production releases. I'm simply turning the versioning scheme off, and it does it by default.

Comment: You'll need to create a task in PowerShell that reads in the version from the .csproj XML, then sets the version variable. Here's another post that explains how to do it in PowerShell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297040/powershell-get-version-from-csproj-file